# What is the best db architecture to capture user data related to a product table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

This is a fictitious example to try to illustrate some design choices I have...any thoughts or links deeply appreciated.

---

Imagine we have a MySQL database with a table (call it libTBL) that contains a row for each book in a library.

This table will be updated, by admins, as new books are added.

Users will be able to create a library of such books - that is, a list representing THEIR selected books.

Users can add a personal, private comment to each book and other meta data (when they started reading it, a review etc).

Users can also add their own books, but these books should not appear in the libTBL table.

What are best practices for capturing this user data?

- When a user is created, create a row in a new table, with each book in the libTBL represented, so IF the user adds notes or other data we already have a home for it?

  - Create a new row in a user library table only when they make a note on a specific book?
    -- One use case, though, is a user ordering their subset library...which would require a new row for each book they order (or all of them, depending on how ordering was implemented).
  - Use bookID and userID to query a user table for custom values for a particular book?

Comment: I'd have one table for books and one for users. Then simply create a user_book join table, which may contain metadata, and a library user that will "own" all the library books. If a user adds a library book to their own library then just add that to the join table (ie book id 1049 and user id 1337). This will allow users to add new books and the library will still only show their own books.

Comment: Put all the books in the same table but have a flag or field identifying source. You can exclude user-contributed books easily using a `WHERE` clause, like `WHERE source IS NULL or source IN (user_id)` for a user's own books plus those there by default.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your thoughts...